# 1 pixel gap between 2 absolute div with 50% height, only on mobile (viewport)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that takes 100% height and split into 4 parts (topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright), each taking a quarter of the screen with absolute positions and sizes (width:50%, height:50%).

On desktop no problem. But on mobile, due to viewport scaling, 1 have 1 pixel gap between the top blocks and the bottom blocks.

I've tried changing the height value of each block according to height of the page manually (make the wrapper's height an even number). Didn't work.
I've now tried a different approach. The wrapper is actually 0px high and sits in the middle of the screen (height:0, top:50%). The top blocks are positioned with bottom:0 and the bottom ones with top:0.
But I still get this weird gap on iPad and mobiles.

Any idea?

https://jsfiddle.net/hywg8qmb/

```css
body{
  background-color:#fff;
}
.full-cache-item{
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
.full-cache-topleft{
    bottom:0;
    left: 0; 
}
.full-cache-topright{
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
}
.full-cache-bottomleft{
    top:0;
    left: 0; 
}
.full-cache-bottomright{
    top:0;
    right: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="full-cache" data-rel="-7">
      <div class="full-cache-item full-cache-topleft"></div>
      <div class="full-cache-item full-cache-topright"></div>
    
      <div class="full-cache-item full-cache-bottomleft"></div>
      <div class="full-cache-item full-cache-bottomright"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Include your relevant HTML and CSS here please. A codepen or jfiddle would be nice

Comment: Nice design anyway :)

Comment: Sub-pixel rounding would be my guess.

Comment: OMG what a preload! 11.3 MB before being able to access the site? 74 HTML requests, among which several pictures over 1MB? 1.50 minute loading (on my mobile emulator); man you can't do that, you just can't, especially on mobile. People will be gone long before the end of the preloading.

Comment: I know why it happens. For example, my browser window is 1225px wide. But if we want to divide it by 2, the result will be 612.5px, but your code rounds it to 613px. So, two elements cover each other with just one pixel gap, so almost black + almost black = really dark almost black :D

Comment: @JeremyThille I gave up after about 20 seconds

Comment: @JeremyThille sadly, it depends on the internet speed, because it took me about 7 seconds :/

Comment: Anyway @Antoine, if you want a perfect 4/4 layout, position and size your divs using `50vw` (50% window width) and `50wh` (50% window height). 100% height doesn't work, for `100%` means `100% of the width` of the parent, not its height.

Comment: @PDKNight yes, that's why I used a mobile emulator. With a decent internet connection on a desktop computer, 11MB would be loaded in a few seconds. But on a mobile network, it's quite... different. So I used Chrome's emulator with network throttling.

Comment: I'm seeing a 1px gap (both vertical and horizontal) on desktop Safari.  The issue isn't just a mobile issue.

Comment: @JeremyThille which emulator do you use? sounds cool.

Comment: Wow, nice feedback, thanks! :) I'm not targeting any mobile, more like ipads at home, for luxury clients. Thanks for the comment on vh, I'll try that. And setup a codepen as well to make it easier to work with.

Comment: @PDKnight Chrome's integrated emulator. Hit F12, then at the top left of the developers tools, activate the mobile emulator (phone icon). Then you can choose your model, pixel aspect ratio, network throttling, override the user agent, etc. Yes, Chrome is great :) Antoine: phone, tablet, whatever : you just can't have a 11MB preloader and 74 HTTP requests before accessing a site. Use lazy loading. Solutions exist.

Comment: @JeremyThille "100% height doesn't work, for `100%` means `100% of the width of the parent`" That's not true at all. Where did you read that? Height always inherits from height.

Comment: Uh, I must admit I saw that one day in a video on CSS-tricks, but I can't find the exact source. I'll tell you if I find it